# How to make ubuntu recognize an external screen when laptop is docked during boot

Tags: boot, multiple-monitors, nvidia-optimus, docking, framebuffer

Consider the following scenario:

- I connect my Thinkpad (with optimus) to my docking station
- Boot the laptop

Than I want that ubuntu recognizes that the laptop is docked and that an external monitor is available (via DP on the docking station) in early boot stage (before it asks for the `dm-crypt` password), loads the nvidia graphics (`prime-select nvidia`) and uses the external screen instead of the laptop lcd.

How can I do this?